# How can I shuffle a list with no repetition?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

```
array1=[3, 7, 11, 12, 15, 5, 1, 4]
array2=[14, 10, 9, 16, 2, 13, 6, 8]
```

I shuffled these arrays.

```
shuffled1 = sorted(array1, key=lambda k: random.random())
shuffled2 = sorted(array2, key=lambda k: random.random())
```

However, I do not want the same numbers to come to the same indexes again. For example: 3 and 14 at index 0, 7 and 10 at index 1. I don't want these numbers to be reciprocal again. All numbers need to be couple with another number.

For example:

```
 shuffled1 =[1, 15, 4, 12, 7, 5, 3, 11]
 shuffled2 =[13, 8, 9, 14, 2, 16, 6, 10]
```

İf shuffled arrays not like this, shuffle again.

Comment: "_İf shuffled arrays not like this, shuffle again._" - what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: I want to output like example that I gave. How can I take like this output?

Comment: For example: Pair of 3 is 14. After shuffle pair of 3 can not be 14.

Comment: Just keep shuffling until your condition is met.

Comment: I can shuffle, it is not problem. How can I check pairs of number? For example after shuffle if 3 at index 5 in shuffled1 and 14 at index 5 in shuffled2, it is fault. Pairs of 3 cannot be 14. How can I check all pairs?

Comment: Why not just use `random.shuffle` to shuffle?

Comment: I shuffle 2 different array.  So after shuffle I need to check pairs.  @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Okay, but the strategy is still to try shuffling, and then see if it was an acceptable shuffle?

Comment: "see if it was an acceptable shuffle?" How :D @Andrej Kesely answer is working by the way. But it is hard code to understand :D

Answer (score 0):

As first step you can create a dictionary that will be used if shuffled lists `array1` and `array2` don't contain the values from initial state. Then we repeat shuffling until the condition is met.

For example:

```
from random import random

array1=[3, 7, 11, 12, 15, 5, 1, 4]
array2=[14, 10, 9, 16, 2, 13, 6, 8]

disallowed_dict = {}
for a, b in zip(array1, array2):
    disallowed_dict.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

while any(b in disallowed_dict[a] for a, b in zip(array1, array2)):
    array1 = sorted(array1, key=lambda _: random())
    array2 = sorted(array2, key=lambda _: random())

print(array1)
print(array2)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[1, 15, 4, 7, 5, 11, 12, 3]
[16, 6, 10, 13, 8, 14, 9, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had completely missread the condition. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from random import randint

array1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def  my_shuffle(array1, array2):
        narray1 = np.array(array1)
        idxs = []

        for element in array1:
                idx = randint(0,len(array1)-1)
                while idx in idxs:
                        idx = randint(0,len(array1)-1)
                idxs.append(idx)
                narray1[idx] = element

        narray2 = np.array(array2)
        it = 0
        idxs2 = []
        for element in array2:
                idx = randint(0,len(array2)-1)
                while idx in idxs2 or idx == idxs[it]:
                        idx = randint(0,len(array2)-1)
                idxs2.append(idx)
                it+=1
                narray2[idx] = element


        return narray1, narray2

new1, new2 = my_shuffle(array1, array1)

print(f"{new1}\n{new2}")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but can you check again :D  For example: 12 and 16 are pairs at index 4. Their indexes are changing but there are still pair at index 7. They can not be pair. Can you check it again please.

Comment: I had missread the condition it had to satisfy, sorry. Test the new one, please